# Can I provide solrconfig.xml and schema.xml files dynamically to Solr server?

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, indexing

I want to perform indexing and searching on data for multiple schemas, i.e. dynamically I want to decide do index for this specific schema and do search on this specific schema.

From my knowledge we need to configure **schema.xml** and **solrconfig.xml** files for index and search structure, which are in the solr folder on the file system. So how can I dynamically create and provide them. 
Is it possible?

I am using solr 4.0, Java, GWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr supports [CREATE and RELOAD commands](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#CREATE), which allow you to load new Cores/Collections dynamically. You still need to generate the xml files. You can, however, start with basic schema.xml with all the required types and add actual fields later using [new Solr REST API](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaRESTAPI).

Or you might be able to push definitions into Zookeeper if you are running Solr in Cloud mode instead of having files on the file system.